# How to move scroll bar up by one line? (In C# RichTextBox)

Tags: c#, richtextbox, scrollbar

For my C# RichTextBox, I want to programmatically do the same thing as clicking the up arrow at the top of a vertical scroll bar, which moves the RichTextBox display up by one line.  What is the code for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's what I do:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsg, 
                               UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

then call:

```
SendMessage(myRichTextBox.Handle, (uint)0x00B6, (UIntPtr)0, (IntPtr)(-1));
```

Seems to work OK - you might need to tweak things a bit, though.

Hope that helps.

Comment: where should i call SendMessage?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference the EM_LINESCROLL message is what you send to any multi-line edit control to set the scroll position. You can scroll vertically or horizontally.
See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761615(VS.85).aspx) for details.

You can also use the Rich Edit Selection method, where you set the character index (which you can get with EM_LINEINDEX) then call RichEdit.ScrollToCaret ie:

```
RichEdit.SelectionStart = SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_LINEINDEX, ScrollTo, 0);
RichEdit.ScrollToCaret();
```

This will scroll that line to the top of the edit control.

Answer (score 0):

window.scrollBy(0,20);

This will scroll the window.  20 is an approximate value I have used in the past that typically equals one line... but of course font size may impact how far one line really is.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the scroll control for the rich text box, you should be able to get its SmallChange property and use that to scroll the text.