# Autoscrolling in RichTextBox C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, richtextbox

How can I do that if I append some text the RTB will automatically scroll down?

Now I'm using:

```
conversationRtb.Rtf = tab.conversationRtb.Rtf;
conversationRtb.SelectionStart = conversationRtb.Text.Length;
conversationRtb.ScrollToCaret();
```

But it isn't working well. Sometimes it doesn't scroll to end but one line before end.

[image: rtb scroll down bug]

Sometimes it makes a big offset.

[image: rtb scroll down bug]

I cannot find why. Is there any another way how to scroll down? I've found `AutoScrollOffset` but no examples how it works.

Comment: These two posts might help. They use `User32.dll` to scroll instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535102/inconsistent-results-with-richtextbox-scrolltocaret http://www.dutton.me.uk/2011/08/31/richtextbox-scrolltocaret-bug/

Comment: I'd rather don't use user32.dll. I'm using mono and I've problems with external libraries.

Comment: Ok. I've just add condition. If Windows do @keyboardP solution else do default ScrollToCaret. Seems to works fine.

Comment: The "dutton.me.uk" link in the comment from @keyboardP seems broken, but here's a working equivalent: http://www.dutton.me.uk/2011-08-31/richtextbox-scrolltocaret-bug/ ( notice that the slashes are now hyphens in the URL ). ;-)

Answer (score 8):

You can adjust `HideSelection value to false`, the AppendText will trigger the correct scroll.

Comment: I've tried but not work for me :(

Comment: you are on winforms ??? or wpf (ScrollToEnd)

Comment: Ohh sorry, yes I'm using winforms. I've updated tags.